# Prove $\|x-y\|\|x+y\|\le\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: inequality

Prove $\|x-y\|\|x+y\|\le\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2$  for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$

I've been struggling with this for a while and haven't figured out a way to do it either geometrically or algebraically.

Comment: Presumably what you mean is "for all $x$ and $y$ in ${\bf R}^n$".

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: OK. Are you aware that $|x\cdot y|\le\|x\|\|y\|$?

Comment: Yes. Shwartz inequality.

Comment: Hint: Square both sides, and expand the norms, e.g. $\|x - y\|^2 = \|x\|^2 - 2\langle x, y \rangle + \|y\|^2$.

Comment: So, apply Schwartz to $(x-y)\cdot(x+y)$.

Comment: Ah! That works so well (and so easily). Thank you so much.

Comment: OK, now that you see how to do it, write it up and post it as an answer (this site encourages people to post answers to their own questions. Then, after some time has passed, you can accept your answer by clicking in the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
\|x-y\|^2\|x+y\|^2 &=(x-y,x-y)(x+y,x+y)\\
&=(\|x\|^2-2(x, y) + \|y\|^2)(\|x\|^2+2(x,y) + \|y\|^2)\\
&=(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)^2-4(x, y)^2\\
&\le(\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2)^2
\end{align}